# How to avoid " Save password to Google? " popup after login page in Android app

Tags: android

Step

1. For android app, when user enter userid and password and click on login button.
2. If login is successful then on next page it will show native popup as - Save password to Google?
3. If user click Save button on popup, then device will save userid and password in Google account setting.
4. So when user tries to login with same app, then thosed saved userid and password will be auto popuplated as suggetion with userid text box.

Can you some suggest solution for
How to avoid " Save password to Google? " popup after login page in Android apk app
How to avoid " Auto fill credential popup for userid and password textbox " in Android apk app

Can you some suggest solution for
How to avoid " Save password to Google? " popup after login page in Android apk app
How to avoid " Auto fill credential popup for userid and password textbox " in Android apk app

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can stop this, although it will disable the autofill for your username / password fields.

Disable autofill for the login fields:

1. In your XML layout file for the login page of your app, locate the
   EditText views for the username and password fields.
2. Add the attribute android:importantForAutofill="no" to these
   EditText views.
3. This disables autofill service not to suggest or save credentials
   for these fields.

Disable autofill service for the whole app:

1. Open the AndroidManifest.xml for your app.
2. Look for the  tag.
3. Inside the  tag, add the following line:

   android:autofillHints="false"

I hope this helps!!

Comment: On which tag should I add `android:autofillHints="false"`?